# IndexError in a large a string

Tags: python, psycopg2

I have a string with `6000` IDS, each ID have `7` characters.

When I use `"""DELETE from t1 WHERE "ID" in (%s)""", ids` I get the following error:

```
[2021-12-09, 10:15:07 -03] {spark_submit.py:523} INFO - c.execute("""DELETE from t1 WHERE "ID" in (%s)""", ids)

[2021-12-09, 10:15:07 -03] {spark_submit.py:523} INFO - IndexError: string index out of range
```

Is there a way to solve this problem with the size of the string without deleting each id one by one?

Update with @niko request:

```
[2021-12-09, 12:31:14 -03] {spark_submit.py:523} INFO - c.execute("""DELETE from marketing.client WHERE "ID" in (%s)""", (ids,))
[2021-12-09, 12:31:14 -03] {spark_submit.py:523} INFO - psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near ")"
[2021-12-09, 12:31:14 -03] {spark_submit.py:523} INFO - LINE 1: DELETE from marketing.client WHERE "ID" in (())
```

Comment: Object `ids` is a string?

Comment: Yes. I get the this string using `ids = ",".join(str(x) for x in df.select("ID").rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect())`. This returns me a value like `1, 2, 3, 4, 5,...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `psycopg2`, you should pass a `tuple` as second parameter in the `execute` method which contains all the parameters for the query, e.g.

```
c.execute("SELECT * from table where id = %s", (1,))
```

When passing a list of ids, you have to use a tuple inside of the tuple, e.g.

```
c.execute("SELECT * from table where id in %s", ((1, 2, 3),))
```

---

**Edit**

In your case, try changing

```
ids = ",".join(str(x) for x in df.select("ID").rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect())
```

to

```
# Make it a tuple of integers
ids = tuple(int(x) for x in df.select("ID").rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect())
```

i.e. since you're querying a BigInt colum, you want `ids` to be a tuple of integers.

And then running

```
c.execute("""DELETE from t1 WHERE "ID" in %s""", (ids,))
```

Comment: Using this solution I got the following message. `invalid input syntax for type bigint: ""`. I forgot to mention, the IDs in DB are bigint.

Comment: @OdiumPura Could you paste the output of `c.mogrify("""DELETE from t1 WHERE "ID" in (%s)""", ids)` (This will output the SQL statement). Maybe replaces `ids` with `ids[:3]` so the output is more compact.

Comment: Yes, just a moment

Comment: When I try to use `c.mogrify` I get `IndexError: string index out of range`

Comment: I suspect your list `ids` contains (empty) strings when it should be integers only (see the edit). Double check your `ids` object.

Comment: I've edited the original post with the complete output for your first solution. I'll try your edit now...

Comment: I've edited again with the output of your last suggestion, still getting an error.

Comment: @OdiumPura Again, make sure ` ids` is a tuple of ints and remove the parenthesis in the SQL template, i.e. `DELETE from t1 WHERE "ID" in %s` (removed parenthesis around `%s`)

Comment: Now it's working! Thank you so much!!!